# Using variables and mixins in Foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I've found a lot of similar questions to this one but nothing that quite solves my problem. Basically, I'm using foundation 4.x with rails 3.x, everything is working fine with foundation_and_overrides being included in my application.css. I can modify the variables in foundation_and_overrides and it all works fine. However, I want to use the $primary-color variable (and a bunch of others) in one of my other scss files (application/global.css.scss). If i use @import "foudation_and_overrides" in my global css file, then it works, but it includes the entire Foundation CSS twice in my compiled application.css, which is obviously not ideal.

I also want to use mixins, such as @include radius() in my global file. This works if I use @import "foundation/components/global" - but then this also ends up with duplicate CSS being compiled. All I want to do is use the global vars & functions, not the CSS - surely this is a really common thing to do?

Previously (before foundation) I just put all my scss functions in a helpers file, and imported this in all other scss files that needed it.

Another quick Q while I'm here, what class do I use to add the little dropdown triangle thing next to some custom text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With new foundation you do:

```
$include-html-global-classes: false;
@import "foundation/components/global";
```

- Updated for even newer foundation (see commentS)

Earlier path was

```
@import "foundation/foundation-global";
```

Comment: Path was @import "foundation/components/global"; but otherwise this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As James said you can set the variable $include-html-classes to false and it won't copy any of the styles to the css. You can add the following lines to any scss sheet to get access to variables and mixins.

```
$include-html-classes: false;
@import "foundation";
```

Comment: I have an issue, that code includes some gibberish into the output. http://pastebin.com/kPMy36Na

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of Sass variables named something like, include-grid-css or something like this in _settings.scss or _variables.scss. You can turn them off so it doesn't generate all of those standard presentational classes. If you are confused, just jump into the source of one these and you will see at the bottom of the file, there is an if statement that causes all of that css to be generated with the mixins at the top of the file. Hope this hepls.

Answer (score 0):

## Keep only settings in *foundation_and_overrides.scss*

Remove the following line at the end of the file *foundation_and_overrides.scss*:

```
@import "foundation";
```

And maybe rename *foundation_and_overrides.scss* to a more appropriate *foundation_settings.scss*.

**Uncomment all settings that you will use in your SASS files.** This also makes explicit which Foundation settings you will use in your application files.

## Use @import in *application.scss*

In "application.scss" make sure to use `@import` instead of `require` for both Foundation and its settings.

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "foundation_settings";
@import "foundation";
```

## Use Foundation settings in your application files

You can simply add the following line in your files that need to access to Foundation variables:

```
@import "foundation_settings";
```

I haven't tested this with mixins yet, but for variables it works and prevents duplicated code.